# Trying to reach files which are configured as PermitedAll ends with forbidden error

Tags: angular, security, spring-boot, spring-security, static-content

I have a `WebSecurityConfig` class which aim is to configure security path:

```
   @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/#/").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/static/index.html").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/static/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    // We filter the api/login requests
                    .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/api/auth", authenticationManager()),
                            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in header
                    .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),
                            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**");
        }
    }
```

Because of the fact that I have a `controller` which forward all requests to `index.html`it should be permited to all:

```
@Controller
public class ViewController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/#/")
    public String index() {
        return "forward:/index.html";
    }
}
```

And all static content also should be available because all `Angular 4` files are copied to static resources and it looks like:
[Files under resource/static directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZ4sx.png)

**BUT** when I run the app the first page which I see is a blank page with `403` errors like:
[Errors in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3CIH.png)

Does anyone have any clue if you see any bug in paths or suspect where that bug could be?

**UPDATE:**
I have added new class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

}
```

and chagned a bit above class to:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/static/index.html").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/#/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            // We filter the api/login requests
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/api/auth", authenticationManager()),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in header
            .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a class that `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`? You need that to define your static content.

Comment: Please see the update. Unfortunately still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("redirect:/index.html");
    }
```

You most probably don't need these lines.

```
.antMatchers("/static/index.html").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/#/").permitAll()
```

You're also going to need to add `@ComponentScan("com.something.something")` for spring to know where to look stuff.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.name.project")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

Comment: Why do you have `assets`? What it has in common with my example?

Comment: It's how Angular 4 structure works, wasn't sure if you have that on AngularJS. If you don't have it; you don't need it.

Comment: Should I change something in `configure`  method? See question

Comment: If that doesn't work, try adding `security.oauth2.resource.filter-order = 3` this line to your `application.properties` file. That may solve the 403 problems.

Comment: Does it throw any error? and have you tried updating the application.properties?

Comment: Yes I updated the `application.properties`. If you are able I can give access to my repo and you can see closer

Comment: Sure. Could to post a link?

Comment: Ok. Can you create a stackoverflow chat? There we can talk?

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough reputation. Here is the link to download all repo: https://files.fm/u/ectk33zz

Comment: So I had a look and I've managed to fix most of the error except one, which is JWT error as I haven't used JWT before. But without it; it works just fine. Here's a link to updated files. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtAbiLrw8PUSozMsM1YiQwNf8CeB There is a text file that explains few things I've changed and the logs of the error so you get more understanding of it.